# What kind of exception is thrown by boost::ifind_first?

Tags: c++, boost

I've always found the boost documentation fairly frustrating to read and despite my best effort, I cannot determine what kind of exception may get thrown in a call to boost::ifind_first. The documentation notes:

> This function provides the strong exception-safety guarantee

However there are no notes on what type of exception may get thrown. So my primary question is how do you determine what exception may be thrown by ifind_first?

Comment: It never throws any exception on its own, it only passes-on exceptions thrown by the callbacks you pass.

Answer (score 0):

It is a tough answer since, as you stated, their documentation could use a kick in the butt.  That being said when boost says:

> This function provides the strong exception-safety guarantee

They are refering to [Exception-Safety in Generic Components](http://www.boost.org/community/exception_safety.html) which states:

> The strong guarantee provides full “commit-or-rollback” semantics. In
>   the case of C++ standard containers, this means, for example, that if
>   an exception is thrown all iterators remain valid. We also know that
>   the container has exactly the same elements as before the exception
>   was thrown. A transaction that has no effects if it fails has obvious
>   benefits: the program state is simple and predictable in case of an
>   exception. In the C++ standard library, nearly all of the operations
>   on the node-based containers list, set, multiset, map, and multimap
>   provide the strong guarantee.4).

I would look into using [`boost::exception`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/exception/doc/exception.html) class to catch a general exception, feed it data that should break it and figure out what it throws from there.

Comment: Not a complete answer but I figured posting something partial would get it off the ground.